# Recurring line output PHP - Concatenated fgets

Tags: php

I'm working on a test site that presents real estate like information on a search.  Alongside images of the houses there are descriptions brought in through directory access.  I have all the lines working correctly, except for the "Description:" line.  In the text files each category is separated by line, except the "Description:" category runs after the title line and into multiple lines up to the end of the file.  I am using a concatenated fgets to get the info, but in my results the output is showing the complete house information correctly including the "Description:" line, but on each following result the house information repeats what it previously printed and then the rest of the next file.  If I get rid of the concatenation and just do a regular:

```
$pos = stripos($line, 'Description:');

if($pos !== false)
{
$description = substr($line, 12);
$description = trim($description);
}
```

Then I end up with only the "Description:" printing without the text of the description section.

This is an example of the imported text file:

City: OceanCove
Price: $950,000
 
Bedrooms: 5
Baths: 3 
Footage: 3000 sq. ft.
Realtor: Shirley Urkiddeng
Grabber: Fantastic Home with a Fantastic View!
Description:
 
You will never get tired of watching the sunset
from your living room sofa or the sunrise
from your back porch with a view overlooking
the gorgeous coral canyon.  Once in a lifetime
opportunity!

Here is my code (in the "Description" section there is some commented out other trials that I did:

```
     <?php
$findhome = $_POST['findhome'];

$header = getHeader($findhome);
print $header;

getResults($findhome);

    function getHeader($findhome)
    {
if (empty($findhome))
    {
        $header = "<h3>Current Listings: <br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $header = "<h3>Current Listings that match: $findhome </h3><br />";
    }

    return $header;

    }

    function getResults($findhome)
    { 


if (empty($findhome))
{
    $findhome ='ALL';
}

$dirname = 'images';

$dirhandle = opendir($dirname);

if ($dirhandle)
{
    $houseimagesarray = array();

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirhandle)))
    {
        if ($file !='.' && $file !='..')
        {
            $first_6 = substr($file,0,6);

            if($first_6 =='house_')
            {
                array_push($houseimagesarray, $file);
            }
        }
    }
}

sort($houseimagesarray);

    $description = '';

foreach ($houseimagesarray as $image_filename)
{


//***************************************************
//** Function Definitions
//***************************************************

    //Get Image Files

            $imagename ='images/'.$image_filename; //.jpg files
            $house_img = "<p><img src='".$imagename."'></p>";

            $houseinfo_filename = str_replace ('.jpg', '.txt',           $image_filename);

            $filename = 'data/'.$houseinfo_filename; //.txt file

            $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');


    //Get Image House Information


    $show_house = 'Y';  //Set default value

    while(true)
    {
        $line = fgets($fp);

        if (feof($fp))
        {
            break;
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'City:');

        if ($pos !== false)
        {
            $city = substr($line, 5);
            $city = trim($city);

            if ($findhome != 'ALL')
            {
                $subpos = stripos($city, $findhome);

                if($subpos === false)
                {
                    $show_house = 'N';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Price:');

        if ($pos !==false)
        {
            $price = substr($line, 6);
            $price = trim($price);
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Bedrooms:');

        if ($pos !== false)
        {
            $bedrooms = substr($line, 9);
            $bedrooms = trim($bedrooms);
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Baths:');

        if ($pos !== false)
        {
            $baths = substr($line, 6);
            $baths = trim($baths);
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Footage:');

        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $footage = substr($line, 8);
            $footage = trim($footage);
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Realtor:');

        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $realtor = substr($line, 8);
            $realtor = trim($realtor);
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Grabber:');

        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $grabber = substr($line, 8);
            $grabber = trim($grabber);
        }

        $pos = stripos($line, 'Description:');

        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $descriptionFlag = "Y";
        }
        if($descriptionFlag=='Y')
        {
            $description .=$line."<br />\n";
            //$description =$line."<br />";
            //$description = $description.$line."<br />";
        } 
    }

    if ($show_house == 'Y')
    {
        print $house_img;

        print "<h3>".$grabber."</h3><br />";
        print "City: ".$city."<br />";
        print "Bedrooms: ".$bedrooms."<br />";
        print "Baths: ".$baths."<br />";
        print "Price: ".$price."<br />";
        print "Footage: ".$footage."<br />";
        print "Realtor: ".$realtor."<br />";

        print $description;

      }


      }
     }  
    ?>
```

New Code:

```
    $pos = stripos($line, 'Description:');

        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $descriptionFlag = "Y";
        }
        if($descriptionFlag=='Y')
        {
            if(!feof($fp))
            {
                $description .=$line."<br />\n";

                if(feof($fp))
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Description` may contain more than one line, you have to loop over the lines until you're done with the `Description` field. If you have multiple items in the same file you'll probably want to search for the next `City` in order to bail-out. Something like:

```
if($descriptionFlag=='Y') {
  while ($line = fgets($handle, 8192)) {
      $line = trim($line);
      if($line === 'City')
        break;
      $description = $description . " " . $line;
  }
  $description = $description . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Didn't get that to work.  I was wondering if there was a way to work it the way I have and getting it to recognize feof? I tried what I added up above in the new code section.

Comment: The code that you added checks for feof alright, but it doesn't `loop` the description content. Try using my code and change only the line: `if($line === 'City')` to: `if(feof($fp))`

Comment: Will try, what's the "8192" stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($descriptionFlag=='Y') {
  while ($line = fgets($handle, 8192)) {
      $line = trim($line);
      if(substr($line,0,4) === 'City')
        break;
      $description = $description . " " . $line;
  }
  $description = $description . "<br />\n";
}
```